# Questions about public static WebView in Java

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a **public static WebView** that named *webView* in my MainActivity.
I can handle with it in MainActivity, use some normal operations like *webView.loadUrl()*

```java
public static WebView webView;

webView.loadUrl();
```

Now I want to **use this static object in other Activity**, and here's the problem: I can't even get it.

```java
Log.i("MYTAG","work!");
Log.i("MYTAG",MainActivity.webView.getUrl());
Log.i("MYTAG","reload");
```

Here I print the url of this webView, but it only executes to the fist step that it only print "work" and skips these next steps. Similarly, it can't executes command "webView.loadUrl()".

You can simply recurrence this by creating a public static WebView object in a class and try to use it in other class.
Thank you very much if you can give me some ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gabe Sechan, I get a new idea and have worked it successfully.
Another activity can't change the webView in my MainActivity directly, but its change can be posted by broadcast. So I finally use a receiver in MainActivity to get the message and change the webView.

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER have a static view.  Views are linked to a single instance of an Activity.  Not only will trying to display it in another activity not work, it will cause a HUGE memory leak because it has a reference to its original activity inside it.

Comment: I see, so how can I change this view in other activities?

Comment: You wouldn't.  Activities shouldn't know about other activities.  However its ok for multiple views to share data, and for changes in that data to cause other activities to change themselves when it reloads.